# Do Remote Desktop Cerificates with internal PKI get auto renewed?

Tags: certificate, rdp, certificate-authority

I'm in the processes of setting up an ADCS PKI in a lab enviroment and I'm testing the use of certificates for RDP to prevent the common RDP self signed certificate warning, and to achieve higher security. I've used this [guide](https://www.derekseaman.com/2013/01/creating-custom-remote-desktop-services.html) for it. By using Group Policies and a certificate template the servers automatically get the needed certificates. Now I can't seem to find any information wheter these certificates also automatically renew themselfs? Or do i need to something else for them to renew, like using the template - renew all certificate holders feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to discuss the guide you used in the deployment. Probably, it is just a copy/paste of an RDS Team blog. Original guide is published by RDS team is correct: [Configuring Remote Desktop certificates](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Enterprise-Mobility-Security/Configuring-Remote-Desktop-certificates/ba-p/247007). This guide is valid for operating systems from Windows Server 2008 R2 and up to Windows Server 2019. If you use this guide correctly, then RDS certificates will be renewed automatically.

Comment: Alright thanks! I compared the steps from the offical guide and It seems my guide was a copy/paste of the offical one. Therefor I assume that the templates get auto-renewed.